# Jenkins Slave Installation as windows service

Tags: windows, jenkins

I'm unable to install Jenkins slave as Windows service and getting the following exception:

```
WMI.WmiException:AccessDenied
```

Comment: This is an error reported by the Windows service?

Comment: I am not sure about it,I am getting this exception while trying to install the slave as windows service.

Comment: Got solution.just start the command line or browser which way you select to install slave using admin rights.problem solved :)

Comment: Nice, happy to hear your problem is solved :) Maybe you can post a solution and vote for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you facing the access denied issue for install as windows service after installing the jenkins.war.

Just close everything.
- Run command prompt with Admin rights.
- Proceed to your jenkins directory using cd (or just copy paste the path into the command prompt).
- Run the command: java -jar jenkins.war
- wait for jenkins to be up.
- Login into the Jenkins
- Manage Jenkins > Select install as Windows service.
-  This will install it as windows service.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the slave using admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

run slave-agent.jnlp using admin cmd.
and then try for install as service option under file.
it will work.